# Could the profile/developer story real name warning be clarified?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, real-name

When editing your real name, you get this warning message:

> If you have a Developer Story on Stack Overflow, saving to all communities affects the Full name that employers and visitors to your public CV/Story will see.

Thank you for this. It's really helpful to be aware of potentially exposing that information.

However, it would be nice if that message also said "...if your developer story is set to synchronize your name with your profile..." or better still if it could check what the effect was actually going to be.

I know this seems like a tiny detail, but one of the times one might change a real name field is when transitioning and literally changing one's name, and in that case people tend to want to be exceptionally careful about what changes when and where.